# Upload a file to solr with my own parameters added

Tags: solr, solr-cell

I would like to upload a file (some ms word document) for instance to solr, but I would like to add my own fields to this upload, like the userId of the person who uploaded it or a number of tags. The content of the file must be parsed and searchable and the exta parameters should be added as fields. Therefor I have added the following definition in schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="example" version="1.1">
  <types>
   <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <!-- A general text field that has reasonable, generic
         cross-language defaults: it tokenizes with StandardTokenizer,
     removes stop words from case-insensitive "stopwords.txt"
     (empty by default), and down cases.  At query time only, it
     also applies synonyms. -->
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
 </types>


 <fields>
    <field name="documentId" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
<field name="text" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="metadata_*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
 </fields>

 <uniqueKey>documentId</uniqueKey>
 <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>

</schema>
```

The relevant part of my solrconfig.xml now looks like this:

```
  <equestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                startup="lazy"
                class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="fmap.content">text</str>
   <str name="lowernames">true</str>
   <str name="fmap.documentId">documentId</str>
   <!-- also tried with
   <str name="fmap.literal.documentId">documentId</str>
   and
   <str name="literal.documentId">documentId</str>
   -->
   <str name="uprefix">metadata_</str>

   <!-- capture link hrefs but ignore div attributes -->
   <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
   <str name="fmap.a">links</str>
   <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
  </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

However no matter what combination I try with this command:

```
java -Durl=http://localhost:9090/solr/update/extract?documentId=test -jar post.jar somedoc.pdf
```

or

```
java -Durl=http://localhost:9090/solr/update/extract?literal.documentId=test -jar post.jar somedoc.pdf
```

I keep on getting missing required field for documentId

Regards
Ronald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and the problem was the name of my field "documentId". Turns out there is a problem checking for required fields when the field name ends in "Id" (capital I)

See this other question which helped me figure it out : [Solr - Missing Required Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821782/solr-missing-required-field)

I changed my field name to "id" and all is fine now. This really makes no sense and has probably driven a few people completely crazy

Answer (score 2):

The reason you have 0 docs it probably you are not specifying documentId (or any other *required* fields for that matter), and indexing is failing on that (look up the logs).

You have to just fallow example: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Getting_Started_with_the_Solr_Example

To add any field to document indexed with Tika you have to use *literal* parameter.
In your case it might be:

```
&literal.userId=123&literal.documentId=doc1
```

If you have some other question, please ask (add possibly add some more details: what your command looks like, errors from the log)

Comment: thx for your remarks, I updated my question with some more details

Comment: What about "java -Durl=http://localhost:9090/solr/update/extract -Dparams=literal.documentId=test" Have you tried curl?

Comment: curl "http://localhost:9090/solr/update/extract?literal.documentId=test&commit-true" -F "
file=@voortgang.docx" same error. Using with -Dparams='literal.documentId=test' same error. Sigh, it must be something stupid that I have misconfigured, but what, where?

Comment: I was really puzzled why this was not working for you, however I reproduced your settings and that give me the same problem. I do not know why it's working like that, but once I renamed documentId to something else like "id" or "uid" everything start working again. Good luck!

Comment: well thx for the effort, I will rename it, but have my doubts that the other required fields will work now as well. Will keep you posted

Comment: Other fields took literal values as they should in my tests

Comment: Not sure what you meant by the last remark, but I fail to add any other field besides id as a field. Even after making them not required they still are not added (of course, since it is skipped apparently by the solr cell). I do see that the content of the file is searchable so I might have to resort to do a dealerNumber/userid search on database levels in combination with a content search, allthough I would have liked it when solr could handle this as well

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15001/discussion-between-ronald-and-fuxi)